# R: unable to use html_text2() from rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

(Of note, I have looked for a solution and cannot find one.)

I'm fairly new to posting, so if I get anything wrong, I'd appreciate the chance to modify the question.

In short, I'm scraping documents with `html_text()`.  I noticed it wasn't splitting correctly, and saw that `html_text2()` would do what I needed, but I'm unable to use it.

Here's the code and error:

```
html_text2(html_nodes(sc_f_html_loop[[i]],"p.some_variable")) 

Error in html_text2(html_nodes(sc_f_html_loop[[i]], "p.some_variable")) : 
  could not find function "html_text2"
```

So, originally, the code is supposed to look like this:

```
abc 12 def

hij 34 klm
```

But, using `html_text()`, it's like this:

```
'abc 12 defhij 34 klm'
```

`html_text2()` is supposed to use `<br>` in the html to create a new line between f and h.  Of note, when i try to explicitly link the package to the library:
`rvest::html_text2(...)`, I get this error:

```
Error: 'html_text2' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rvest'
```

Thank you for considering this.  And please let me know if I need to change anything.

Comment: Check your packages. Are rvest (1.0.2) an xml2 (1.3.3)  correctly installed ? Also, be sure to load rvest with library(...) command before calling the function.

Comment: Run and share the result of `sessionInfo()` Maybe you are using an older verion of rvest where that function did not exist.

Comment: What if you try calling it explicitly from the namespace, e.g., `rvest:::html_text2()`?